# Can a chatbot in MS v4 framework be ran in clustermode nodejs with PM2

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Hi I created a chat bot with microsoft v4 framework. Its functioning fine with `nodemon`, `forever` etc. It also functions correctly with `pm2 start` But when started it in cluster mode, the bot behaves unusually. The intents and waterfall are mixing up.

For prompts in v4 which is working fine in normal app start behaves unusual by catching none intent from LUIS

I have a small idea that the context for v4 is getting mixed up with clusters

Can someone shed some light in this matter?

Comment: I'm not sure if  the same solution applies, but when you cluster with PM2 and you want yo provide two way realtime updates using websockets, you need to make each node cluster aware of the other's activity, for example using redis pub/sub. https://medium.com/@codeandcam/clustering-an-express-socket-io-server-with-pm2-789d11865f95

Comment: yes, i can balance it, but the context is getting mixed up while using cluster mode

Comment: @Mukund, I know a fair bit about Bot Framework but nothing about PM2. In cluster mode, is this one bot that is scaled across the CPUs or does it create new instances of the bot on different CPUs?

Comment: @StevenKanberg when i did the research, while i am running pm2 in cluster mode it creates here 3 node processes. so when we run the bot , for user responses depending upon previous responses, if the process id is different, bot cannot recognize it as connected conversation

Comment: @StevenKanberg can we run an app did in nodejs botframework as a multiple instances?

Comment: @Mukund, it sounds like additional logic is needed to be sure the process id is valid, hasn't changed, isn't updated while a conversation is active, is routed correctly, etc. But, again, I don't know PM2 so I can't say for certain if that is an accurate assessment.

Comment: Regarding multiple instances, an Azure bot is simply an extended version of an Azure Web App. Azure Web Apps can be scaled out to run across multiple instances / CPUs. You can read more about scaling in the [AutoScaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-get-started) and [Scaling Out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-get-started?toc=/azure/app-service/toc.json) documents.